# Examples of Finite-Dimensional Space with Non-Vanishing Homology in Higher Dimensions?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes, dimension-theory-analysis, continuum-theory

The Barratt-Milnor Sphere $X_n$ is an $n$-dimensional space which has non-vanishing singular homology in arbitrarily high dimensions. The space $X_n$ is a generalized [Hawaiian Earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring), i.e. the $n$-dimensional Barratt-Milnor Sphere $X_n$ is the one-point compactification of a countable collection of copies of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  So $X_1$ is the classical Hawaiian Earring, for example.

[Here, they prove](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2034486) that if $n > 1$ then the singular homology $H_q(X_n, \mathbb{Q})$ is non-zero whenever $q \equiv 1 \pmod{n-1}$.  So $X_2$ has non-trivial singular homology groups for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The following is the main question:

> Is there a compact, connected metric space $X$ where *some* high-dimensional homology group
> doesn't vanish (higher than the dimension of the space), but where
> singular $\mathbb{Z}$-homology does *eventually* stabilize to zero?

If not, must the collection of $n$ such that $X$ has a non-trivial homology group at dimension $n$ contain an infinite arithmetic progression as the Barratt-Milnor Spheres do?  That might be the key to a disproof, as it feels in the wheelhouse of some cohomological or higher-homotopy argument.

I was also wondering about these questions, which are of a more didactic nature:

1. Is there a more elementary proof that one of these spaces has non-vanishing homology in arbitrarily high dimensions?  Their proof uses Whitehead products and coefficients from $\mathbb{Q}$.
2. What are other spaces where this occurs, especially where the 'reason it happens' is fundamentally different than for the Barratt-Milnor Spheres?
3. Is there a more complicated finite-dimensional space, but where the calculation that a higher-dimensional homology group doesn't vanish is legit-easy?
4. Can there be a one-dimensional space with such behavior? (EDIT: this was answered below in a comment)
5. Can we require the groups in such a space to be torsion (alternatively, torsion-free)?

A related question was asked here by someone else:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268301/is-any-cw-complex-with-only-finitely-many-nonzero-homology-groups-homotopic-to-a

However, no reference was given for this part of the answer, and it's not clear to me why "all but finitely many homology groups" isn't just "all homology groups" or why homotopy-equivalent was used instead of "$n$-dimensional."  Any insights?

EDIT: After two bounties went unanswered, I posted it on MO here.  One of the experts in this sort of stuff responded that they think the factual questions are probably open rn.  Sorry, didn't think that I was asking something that tricky!  I figured such things would be well-known x)

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383511/low-dimensional-spaces-with-high-dimensional-homology

Comment: Your 3 is not possible (the second part). Finite CW complexes have bounded homology and homotopy equivalences preserve homology.

Comment: Yes, but we're not talking about finite CW complexes.  The Barratt-Milnor Spheres are not finite complexes, for example.  My #3 is asking about general spaces; the MO person's version is asking about finite-dimensional, not finite complexes.

Comment: Which is why I refer to the second part of your question 3 which specifically mentions finite dimensional cw complexes. Either you are misinterpreting what they said or they are wrong, is my point.

Comment: Ok yeah, I just saw "finite CW complexes," but it doesn't matter since that's not the relevant part.  I don't think the people dropping answers in that MO thread are actually answering the question in the title.

Comment: Yeah, the answer your linking to isn't focused on pathological spaces, but rather if finiteness properties of CW complexes can be read from homology.

Comment: Just to note, I've edited the question and removed the trivial part of #3.  Connor's comments were accurate.

Comment: For $4$ isn't $X_2$ an example? You also get boring examples by disjoin union of, say $X_3$ and its suspension since suspension just shifts the homology up. Finally I can make a nontrivial comment on one of your questions: The answer to 6 is negative, at least if your spaces are normal, this was proved [here](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/eda-kawamura2.pdf) by Eda and Kawamura

Comment: Nice!  Someone else was telling me about some of Eda's results on homotopy types of curves, seems his work should be better-known.  I am still curious about #5, and whether we can get examples that are torsion, or torsion-free.